# True singleton for whole computer?

Tags: java, single-instance

How to create a real singleton for a whole computer in Java?

I have a console app written in Java. if application is executed for a second time I want it to know that the main application is already running (and executing jobs). The second execution will just allow the user to query data (jobs). I know I can create a file and write everything to it, but then I will have to also support computer resets, etc.

Is there a better way to do it?

to summarize:

- I start the app. It has jobs and execute them at wanten interval.
- I start app for a second time. I get message that jobs are already running and I can query data from the first app.
- Start app for 3rd time and it works the same as the 2nd time.
- If I stop the first instance and start a new one it works like the first instance.

P.S. I do know this question must have been asked more then once, but google and StackOverflow search give me links only relative to Singleton Design Pattern.

Comment: You do this with socket communiction or with something like [terracotta](http://terracotta.org/)

Comment: Singletons aren't a good idea for a single JVM; I think they're even worse for all JVMs on a machine.

Comment: Have your first app connect to a socket as a server.  The others will not be able to bind to that port as a server until the first one dies.  As a bonus, the others could then bind as a client and use that socket to communicate between them.

Comment: You will need *some* kind of inter-process communication, be it files or sockets or even shared memory. What's wrong with using a simple file?

Comment: @RC Oh come on... Zookeper is way too overkill for a task like this one.

Comment: @duffymo what's wrong with singletons? Do you have a link to a rant somewhere? I'd be interested to read it.

Comment: Sure, here's what Google thinks about Singletons: http://code.google.com/p/google-singleton-detector/

Comment: but that is about Singleton Design Pattern. its over-used, but I'm talking about real Singleton here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/43-java-single-application-instance) is a link that'll do what you want.

This provides an example of code that binds to a socket at startup and then if something is bound at startup then it sends a message

You can use this to communitcate between your processes.

Comment: The example specifies a single socket port explicitly. This can be troublesome if some other application uses the same port. An alternative is to allocate the port dynamically, record the port somewhere well-defined (file,db,registry,...), connect to it and confirm identity.

Answer (score 2):

As @PaulTomblin mentioned in the comments, you should probably bind a server socket to a specific port.  This serves 2 purposes.  If the port is currently unbound, then the running process becomes the main instance.  If the port is already bound, then the running process becomes a client and instead connects to the port in order to communicate with the primary instance.